# How many entities a database should have in a real world app?

Tags: sql, database

I was told my somebody for small project table count should be 10-15
some told me more tables better it is.

I don't have a requirement specification because i'm doing a small project at home. but its growing bigger. Typically I don't make requirement specification but end of the day I wish I should've made it.

Anyway, Assume that you are building a industry grade student management system (SMS) for a university and your were given full authority build a SMS system that's would be like an off the shelf package. How many tables would you add for the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit like ["How long is a piece of string?"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how_long_is_a_piece_of_string)

The number of tables in a database depends on the domain model of your application. It is simply impossible to answer your question without doing a data analysis of your case.

There might be huge applications with only one or two database tables, and tiny ones with hundreds. The number in itself is not a good indicator of the quality of the architecture.

As a general rule: One table for each uniquely identifiable type of information *(on a low level)* that you need to store, plus tables for cross-referencing *(for many-to-many relationships)*. And then there might be administrative tables, tables for logging, etc. Try learning about [Object Role Modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Role_Modeling) *(not the same as Object-relational mapping)*, for ways of automatically creating databases based on the facts and constraints of your business model.

In your specific case, I think you need to **stop thinking about how many tables you end up with**. Just keep developing, and when you run into new data that needs storing, refactor your database solution, adding and modifying tables as you go. If you do a good job refactoring, **the number you end up with, is the right one**.

Comment: @atomblad, assume you were doing it, assume you have university near by with an annual intake of 3000 students, it offers Diploma to Phd courses with an academic staff of 150. As an approximation how many tables would u add, I don't need the exact value : ) but I need approximation value

Comment: Well, you're still not telling me about what types of data you would be storing in your database. Are the students and faculty **users** of the application? Or are they what is going into the database? In that case, what information about each student or teacher do you need to store? Just simple name, age, email per person? In that case, probably just one table. More information?

Comment: @atomblad these are the fucntions-student registrations with programs and courses. Store assignments, exams and test scores based on passed courses determine the student is ready graduate basically for a student from start to end of his program. For lecturers basic HR table allocate them to courses etc. The System does not handle library borrowings of student internet logins etc.

Comment: You would probably end up with one table for storing student basic data (name, email, address, etc). One table for lecturers' basic data. One table for programs, and one for courses, one for assignments, one for attempts, etc... Many-to-many relationship link tables connecting some of these tables together... I don't know... Somewhere between 10 and 50 maybe, but I'm taking that number right out of the air... It also depends on your data access approach.

Comment: @atomblad: basic information of student which is not the problems, I know what to store for students and faculty members but without considering library and internet, school system login tracking (which will be on my next version) im just confused how any tables I should be to make it modest, assume there is another app that does monitor student system usage and the blackboard app handles assignment marking

Comment: I think you need to stop thinking about how many tables you end up with. Just keep developing, and when you run into new data that needs storing, refactor your database solution, adding and modifying tables as you go. If you do a good job refactoring, the number you end up with, is the right one.

Answer (score 4):

Though SO is not the right platform to answer this as this is a very opinion based discussion, still from my personal experience I tend to follow a thumb rule-

> "Only bare bones business entities which are absolutely needed must
>   constitute as database entities."

Note that in all terms, database entities is not same as database tables. A normalised entity can be represented as a set of tables.

For a student management system which is an enterprise grade, will have more than 10 business entities for sure. For me these bare minimum 10 will be

- Person
- Class
- Course
- Hostel
- Attendance
- Events
- Marks
- Schedule
- Office
- Comments

Answer (score 3):

Your question is all wrong - it's like asking if it's best to travel on foot, in car or on a plane without knowing how far you need to get.

When you're building an application first and foremost you need to determine what functionality you want to build - you'd typically start off with stories / use cases. As the stories are growing in breadth/depth you'll find you have more entities, I'm talking 3NF here...

Come back to us with some stories/use cases and I can tell you roughly the number of entities. Look at some use case examples - there are tons of them on the internet.